# Error Message Unclear :[$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have created a .html,app.js,Controller.js and Services.js.
I simply wish to publish data on html page using DI but on execution of html file I am getting an error as

```
angular.js:12798 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.12/$injector/unpr?p0=menuFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20menuFactory%20%3C-%20MenuController
```

app.js

```
'use strict'
angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
```

Services.js

```
'use strict'
angular.module('confusionApp')
.factory('menufactory',function(){...
```

Controller.js

'use strict';

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
.controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory',    
function($scope, menuFactory){...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`menuFactory` should be `menufactory` while injecting to the controller

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
.controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menufactory',    
function($scope, menufactory){
```

Comment: Do we have any methods to get specific error for this kind of problems

Comment: you can click the link and check

Answer (score 0):

Its the injector error in the controller

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
    .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menufactory',    
    function($scope, menuFactory){

    }
```

you should provide the correct name for the factory as `menufactory` in the controller, and the `menuFactory` inside the controller function defenition is  the alias name for `menufactory` factory.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the mentioned URL

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=menuFactoryProvider%20%3C-%20menuFactory%20%3C-%20MenuController

In the **Description** you will find answer to your question.

> This error results from the **$injector** being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, **make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly**.

you have spelling mistake.

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
    .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menufactory', function($scope, menuFactory){
});
```

Comment: Ok, can we define our won functions so that we can get specific errors and not as mentioned above

Comment: Angular provide inbuilt support to show common errors. If you want to define your own